# How do I fix an infinite loop in useEffect when passing in a function to a custom hook

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I'm trying to create a 'useApi' hook which takes a function returning a promise. In my current implementation, I get warnings about not including dependencies in the useEffect hook, namely the API promise function I pass to it. However, if I include it in the dependencies, it causes an infinite loop.

I've looked at a lot of questions but I can't seem to solve it.

Please find my sample here: [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-fire-inh7s?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your `fetchData` function has two dependencies that change all the time: `state` and `apiCall`.

`state` changes all the time because you update the state inside the `fetchData` function itself.
The solution to the problem is to get the state from the `setState` function itself like so:

```js
const fetchData = React.useCallback(() => {
  setState((state) => {
    return { ...state, loading: true, response: undefined };
  });
  apiCall()
    .then((response) => {
      setState((state) => {
        return { ...state, response, loading: false };
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      setState({ loading: false, response: undefined, error: err });
    });
}, [apiCall]);
```

This way you can remove the `state` dependency.

`apiCall` also changes all the time because the function is recreated every time the component is re-rendered.
To solve this issue, you need to wrap the `useApi` callback inside a `useCallback` hook:

```js
const [{ error, loading, response }, fetchData, reset] = useApi(
  React.useCallback(() => randomNumberApi(max), [max])
);
```

Now you can have your `useEffect` dependencies without causing an infinite loop:

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
  if (max) {
    fetchData();
  }
}, [fetchData, max]);
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-hill-xkwzy) for the full code.

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, to remove the warnings it's just necessary to remove the brackets on `useEffect` like:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  if (max) {
    fetchData();
  }
}); // remove brackets
```

The problem is that now `useEffect` will be called every time App.js changes his state (I mean always because `fetchData` changes App.js state) and the result is an infinite loop.

To solve this, you could use an `useRef` in this way:

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
...
const firstLoad = useRef(true);
React.useEffect(() => {
  if (max && firstLoad.current) {
    fetchData();
  }
  firstLoad.current = false;
});
```

And `fetchData()` will be called just one time (at first load).

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-goldstine-8rjl1?file=/src/App.js) your codesandbox modified.

Comment: this seems very hacky - better to refactor out the dependency rather than mis-using useRef